# How do I draw an arrow with a bullet on the line?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, decorations, bullets

Using tikzcd I can (roughly) produce what I want:

```
\begin{tikzcd} [column sep = small]
  a \ar[r, "\bullet" {description, inner sep=0, outer sep=0}] & b
\end{tikzcd})
```

yielding

[image: arrow with bullet]

However it is a) inconvenient having to open a tikzcd environment every time I want to draw this arrow, and b) for consistency reasons it would be nice if the "bullet arrow" behaves exactly like `\to` does. (The arrow above is slightly longer than `\to` for example).

It would also be nice if the solution generalizes to `\xrightarrow`.

Comment: What will that symbol stand for? Remember: when you introduce new symbols there might be problems copy and pasting from your pdf, with accessibility, and probably more. Perhaps there is already one of the many existing arrows that fits your needs?

Comment: These kind of arrows are relatively standard in literature about double categories.

Comment: Ah, thanks! A close match is `U+021F4` (right arrow with small circle). I wonder why that was not chosen. Maybe it is already used for something else in that arrow-heavy sub-field of mathematics?

Comment: Well, there is no easy way of incorporating unicode symbols in latex documents by codepoint, or is there? And even if there is, you would still have the issue that you want to dynamically adjust the length of the arrow to the label (like \xrightarrow{} does).

Comment: Easy and easy. If you use luatex or xetex and load unicode-math, you can have the one mentioned above via `\circleonrightarrow`. I don't think there is an extensible version of it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also just stack a bullet over the arrows produced by `\to` and by `\xrightarrow`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\bulletto}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\(\to\)\cr\>\(\bullet\)}}}
\newlength{\arrowlength}
\newcommand*{\xbulletto}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\arrowlength}{\(\xrightarrow{#1}\)}%
    \mathrel{\ooalign{\(\xrightarrow{#1}\)\cr\makebox[\arrowlength][c]{\(\bullet\)}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\(a \to b \quad a \xrightarrow{xyz} b\)

\(a \bulletto b \quad a \xbulletto{xyz} b\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! However when using this solution with \xrightarrow and longer labels, the \dot is no longer in the middle, but at the very left of the line. Do you know a way how to centralize the second table row?

Comment: @PeterGuthmann I added a solution for `\xrightarrow` in my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! In case someone wants to adjust the size of the bullet you can achieve this by replacing `\bullet` with something like `\raisebox{.55pt}{\scalebox{0.8}{\(\bullet\)}}`.